# Conky text overlaps with other text

Tags: conky

Some of the text part of conky are overlapping with itself. As you can see in the 3rd bubble form the top "Disks" is hidden under Root, Home, and Date.

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have installed the conky manager using this [method](http://itsfoss.com/conky-gui-ubuntu-1304/). But I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Original: [left image]

```
# Showing disk partitions: root, home and Data
${voffset 8}
${offset 103}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}HDD[s]
###${offset 120}${diskiograph 33,183 666666 666666}${voffset 12}
${voffset 12}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Swap: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /dev/sda3}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /dev/sda3}
 ${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Home: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Data:  ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /}

# Network data (my desktop have only LAN). ETHERNET ring is mostly useless but looks pretty, main info is in the graphs
${voffset 54}
${offset 103}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}ARPANET
```

Fixed: [right image]

```
# Showing disk partitions: root, home and Data
${voffset 48}
${offset 103}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}HDD[s]
###${offset 120}${diskiograph 33,183 666666 666666}${voffset 12}
${voffset -5}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Swap: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /dev/sda3}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /dev/sda3}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Home: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Data:  ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /}

# Network data (my desktop have only LAN). ETHERNET ring is mostly useless but looks pretty, main info is in the graphs
${voffset 36}
$ {offset 103}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}ARPANET
```

- In this example, the screen shot is the actual visual feedback of my `.conkyrc` config file, which is located in `~/`.

  ---

What you can see, when you carefully compare the screen shot, with the code listed below from both examples is, that i only changed the `${voffset}` parameters, starting from:

```
 # Showing disk partitions: root, home and Data
```

In your case it is the same point of reference, to get started from! Every entry in the code, below of my #HDD[s]-setting needs to be readjusted, always using the `${voffset xx}` parameter, just like in the example.

- I know, it looks quite difficult, but give it some time, and you'll make it work!